# Generate rspec for complex query method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

**Issue**

I have a method in my notification model which return result from a complex query

```
BookMember
  .joins(" INNER JOIN notifications on notifications.reference = book_members.id")
  .joins(:book)
  .select("notifications.*,book_members.id as bookmemid, book_members.invited_by as invited_by, books.book_name as bookname, books.id as bookid")
  .where("notifications.id in (?)",bookset)
```

I want to test it using

```
expect(real_result).to eq expected_result
```

How to generate `expected_result`?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your expected result is?

Comment: Its a complex query which join 3 tables to produce the result. How can I give test the result. For a fetch in one table I test like this,  

      book1 = Book.create(book_name: "Book 1")   
      expected_result = book1             
      real_result = Book.getBook book1.id            
      expect(real_result).to eq expected_result